# XNA - Memory leak while saving frames

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, xna

I use XNA game project for creating frames of my 3D scene. However i got a memory leak while using MemoryStream. Code below is called as a part of Draw function.

```
    byte[] FrameSave()
    {
        int w = GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth;
        int h = GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight;

        //pull the picture from the buffer 
        int[] backBuffer = new int[w * h];
        GraphicsDevice.GetBackBufferData(backBuffer);

        //copy into a texture 
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, w, h, false, GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferFormat);
        texture.SetData(backBuffer);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        texture.SaveAsJpeg(ms, w, h); //MEMORYLEAK

        byte[] zframe = ms.ToArray();

        ms.Close();
        ms.Dispose();
        texture.Dispose();            
        return zframe;
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but try using a `using` statement for your `MemoryStream`. (`using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())`)

Comment: I tried, but it works the same as before.

Comment: Could it be because you are disposing your picture AFTER your memory stream?

Comment: Even after i dispose it immediately after save, it still causes a leak...

Answer (score 0):

Ah i found a response in other thread:

According to this Texture2D.SaveAsJpeg (as well as Texture2D.SaveAsPng) has a memory leak.
The solution is (unfortunately) to create your own texture saving routine.

Thanks XNA. >.>

Comment: A thought. Has Mono Game implemented these and, if so, couldn't you use those routines from the open source project (With proper attributions of course). You could also just target mono game instead of XNA and get the cross platform benefits.